# Rockmelt cannot connect to websites

Tags: rockmelt

Rockmelt stopped working about a week ago. All other browsers - Chrome, IE, Firefox - work fine, but Rockmelt for some reason gives me this error message:

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: i know the screenshot that i provided was comodo. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling rockmelt, and it gave me that same message (just substitute rockmelt in for comodo) so then i tried comodo and still got the same message..but all other browsers still function fine..

Comment: Both are based off chrome I believe, and this looks just like the chrome error message. I used to get this with some sites, but it was an ISP side messup

Answer (score 0):

This may sound obvious but try to reinstall the browser.

Comment: i have done that ..i uninstalled and reinstalled rockmelt still getting same message.  So then i tried Comodo, which i have never used before, and am getting same message...so i then uninstalled comodo and tried to reinstall that as well and get same message...it has to be something in my settings but i dont know what and i dont know where ...lol

Comment: Isn't there an option to return everything to their default settings?

Comment: After uninstall go and delete the program and user files it leaves behind, then reinstall.